# Angular nested for loops in template with global index

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I need to create a 2-level nested list in Angular template and index the items with a global index or with other words breadth-first indexing.

If the item is clicked it should be able to return the index.

Scheme:

- 0 List item

  - 2 List item
  - 3 List item
- 1 List item

  - 4 List item
  - 5 List item

I am trying to traverse this json (you can ignore the root):

```
    data: Data = {
        "name": "Exceptions",
        "color": "white",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "New",
                "color": "peru",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Amount Break",
                        "size": 1,
                        "color": "deepskyblue"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Amount Break",
                        "size": 1,
                        "color": "dodgerblue"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Active",
                "color": "chocolate",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Amount Break",
                        "size": 2,
                        "color": "deepskyblue"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Amount Break",
                        "size": 2,
                        "color": "dodgerblue"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Can you please share your JSON data?

Comment: I posted the json. I have a loop similar to the one Friso mentioned below.

Comment: *I am trying to traverse this json*: what have you tried? Where is the code? Have you googled for "breadth-first"? Have you tried applying the algorithm to your code?

Answer (score 0):

Dose something like this suit your needs?

```
<ul *ngFor="let items of itemsLists; let i = index">
    <li *ngFor="let item of items; let j = index" (click)="logIndex(j)"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That won't help as j will start from 0 again.

Comment: Are all list items coming from the same array?

Comment: It's the json posted above.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use the CSS increment as follows, It is not the same you want but might be work for you:

[See the example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-nl24f6)

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor='let item of list'>    
    List item
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor='let child of list'>Child Item </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  counter-reset: section;                
  list-style-type: none;
}
li::before {
  counter-increment: section;            
  content: counters(section, ".") " ";   
}
```